# How to convert api body x-www-form-urlencoded to raw plain/text

Tags: rest, apigee, api-gateway

I'm setting up oAuth generation in new testing software, Tosca. Tosca can only handle API calls with raw body types. I need to convert below x-www-form-urlencoded payload to plain/text. The request is denied with "developerMessage": "The authentication service denied the request".

I have tried changing all of the ":"'s to "=" and all linebreaks to "&." Which has worked for converting other x-www-form-urlencoded payloads to plain/text. I have removed our client_id and client_secret and added them to basic auth. I have removed any and all special characters and spaces from the body and still getting error.

scope:openid
realm:employer
auth_method:cleartrust
auth_id_user_token:A+B/C/D==
nonce:cd
identity_method:air
response_type:id_token token
grant_type:password

which I changed to

```
scope=openid&realm=employer&auth_method=cleartrust&auth_id_user_token=A+B/C/D==&nonce=cd&identity_method=air&response_type=id_token token&grant_type=password
```

The plain/text api call should get a successful response and bring back oAuth token.

Comment: Have you ever try to assign your content type in your request header? something like assign Content-Type to text/plain.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work for Tricentis in the Support Department.

Tosca's API Engine can also handle url-encoded payloads. See this manual page for an example screenshot: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=12.3.0&url=engines_3.0/api/api_create_url-encoded.htm

Additionally, please follow these steps:

1. In the *Technical View* tab, open the Headers pane on the right-hand side. There enter a *Content-Type* header param with value *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.
2. In the *Auth* tab, select *Basic Auth* as the method and use the **client_id** as the username and the **client_secret** as the password. Tick the checkbox *Pre-authenticate*.
3. In the *Payload* tab, you can enter the url-encoded payload required by your web service. Since you use grant_type = password, the payload has to include at least the string `grant_type=password&username=someUsername&password=somePassword`